# Symmetry 3ds Max

Tags: max, 3ds, symmetry

I made a hand in 3ds Max and after I made the other hand using symmetry. Now I want to separate the 2 hands in order to have 2 objects with which I need to work individually. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After applying symmetry in 3ds max, make sure you collapse the mesh 

**Right click > convert to > editable poly/mesh**)

Then, select one of the hands using the "elements" selection mode (hotkey 5 when in "editable poly" mode), with the current selection, scroll down the "editable poly" modifier panel and find the "Detach" button in the "Geometry" rollout.

**Geometry > Detach**

After clicking "Detach", you will be prompted to rename the detached mesh. Rename it and press "OK".

Then select both objects and set their pivots to their centers (optional)

**Hierarchy tab > affect pivot only > center to object**.

Answer (score 0):

Select one hand (in polygon mode), all of it's polygons,
Then select "Ungroup"
done :)

I think you can right click on the hand after all polygons are selected, "Ungroup" should be a quick option.